# Importing a 3d model already texturized with substance painter in blender

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, external-applications

I'm trying to learn the substance painter tool. So,I have a question to ask. So, I'm planning to texture a model using Substance Painter and will render it using the Cycles Render Engine. Is there a way to import the 3D model in the fbx format already texturized in substance painter directly in blender without applying the shaders and the textures within blender itself ? Thanks.

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/1853.

Comment: What @cegaton said. That said, the metalness/rough materials are pretty simple to setup with the principled shader, just plug the maps into the right slots. And remember to use OpenGl rather than directX normal maps (or flip the green channel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)